# Trying to Change the Encdoing of a File in Java is Doubling the Contents of the File

Tags: java, character-encoding, fileoutputstream

I have a FileOutputStream in java that is reading the contents of UDP packets and saving them to a file. At the end of reading them, I sometimes want to convert the encoding of the file. The problem is that currently when doing this, it just ends up doubling all the contents of the file. The only workaround that I could think to do would be to create a temp file with the new encoding and then save it as the original file, but this seems too hacky.

I must be just overlooking something in my code:

```
if(mode.equals("netascii")){
                byte[] convert = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                input.read(convert);
                String temp = new String(convert);
                convert = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").encode(temp).array();
                fos.write(convert);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Read Successful!");
            fos.close();
        }
```

Is there anything suspect?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should be using a Reader and a Writer here, specifying the appropriate CharSet in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the array of bytes you've read from the InputStream will be converted as if its ascii chars, which I'm assuming its not. Specify the InputStream encoding when converting its bytes to String and you'll get a standard Java string.

I've assumed UTF-16 as the InputStream's encoding here:

```
byte[] convert = new byte[(int)file.length()];
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

// read file bytes until EOF
int r = input.read(convert);
while(r!=-1) r = input.read(convert,r,convert.length);

String temp = new String(convert, Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

Comment: Also, both the question and this answer ignores the return value of the `InputStream.read(byte[])`, which will lead to reading arbitrary number of bytes from the file instead of the full file contents.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin could you elaborate on this? I don't quite understand what the problem with what I have is.

Comment: See the Javadoc for read(). It isn't specified to fill the buffer. It is only obliged to transfer at least one byte. You have to loop.